# How to change the volume of MusicTrack? - iOS develop

Tags: ios, volume

How to change the volume of MusicTrack? - iOS develop

I was play a test.mid with "MusicPlayer Class". And now, I wanna to change the volume of track. How can I do that?

Anybody help~ thanks! ^^

Answer (score 1):

drag one uiview in your xib and change is custom class property to MPVolumeView.this will work only on devide.

Comment: I don't wanna to change the device volume. Only adjust one track in the midi file. Thanks~